# Undefined is not a object React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to navigate from login screen to Tabs screen, But I am getting the following error

> Undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Below is my **Login.js**:

```
 import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements'
import firebase from 'firebase';

const textInputConfig = {
  placeholderTextColor : '#838383',
}

export default class Login extends Component<{}>{

  static navigationOptions = {
     header: null
   }

  login() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Tabs');
  }

  render (){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={require('../resources/images/background_image.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} >
            <Image source={require('../resources/images/app_logo.png')} style={styles.logo}/>
              <View style={styles.formContainer}>
                  <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder='Username'
                      placeholderTextColor={textInputConfig.placeholderTextColor} autoCapitalize='none'/>
                  <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder='Email'
                      placeholderTextColor={textInputConfig.placeholderTextColor} autoCapitalize='none'/>
                  <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder='Password'
                      secureTextEntry={true} placeholderTextColor={textInputConfig.placeholderTextColor} autoCapitalize='none'/>
                  <Button raised title='SIGN UP' buttonStyle={styles.signupButton}
                      containerViewStyle={styles.signupButtonContainer} onPress={() => this.login()} />
             </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
.....
```

Below is my **Router.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

import Home from '../screens/Home';
import MyCards from '../screens/MyCards';
import AddCard from '../screens/AddCard';
import Login from '../screens/Login.js';


export const MainScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
 Home: {
   screen: Home,
  navigationOptions : {
     tabBarLabel: 'Home',
     tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="account-circle" size={35} color={tintColor} />
   },
 },
 MyCards: {
   screen: MyCards,
   navigationOptions : {
    tabBarLabel: 'My Cards',
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="list" size={35} color={tintColor} />
  },
 },
},
 {
   tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
   animationEnabled: true,
   tabBarOptions: {
     activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
   },
 },
);

export const AppNavigation = StackNavigator({
    LoginScreen: { screen: Login },
    Tabs: { screen: MainScreenNavigator},
    AddCard: { screen: AddCard }
  },
  {
   headerMode: 'screen'
 });
```

Can someone please tell what I am doing wrong?

**Edit Login.js:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements'
import firebase from 'firebase';

const textInputConfig = {
  placeholderTextColor : '#838383',
}

export default class Login extends Component<{}>{

  static navigationOptions = {
     header: null
   }

  login = () => {
    console.log("login function");
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Tabs');
  }

  render (){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={require('../resources/images/background_image.png')} style={styles.backgroundImage} >
            <Image source={require('../resources/images/app_logo.png')} style={styles.logo}/>
              <View style={styles.formContainer}>
                  <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder='Username'
                      placeholderTextColor={textInputConfig.placeholderTextColor} autoCapitalize='none'/>
                  <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder='Email'
                      placeholderTextColor={textInputConfig.placeholderTextColor} autoCapitalize='none'/>
                  <TextInput style={styles.textInput} placeholder='Password'
                      secureTextEntry={true} placeholderTextColor={textInputConfig.placeholderTextColor} autoCapitalize='none'/>
                  <Button raised title='SIGN UP' buttonStyle={styles.signupButton}
                      containerViewStyle={styles.signupButtonContainer} onPress={this.login} />
             </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has the reference issue!

Replace `onPress={() => this.login()}` with `onPress={this.login.bind(this)}`

```
<Button raised title='SIGN UP' buttonStyle={styles.signupButton}
                  containerViewStyle={styles.signupButtonContainer} onPress={this.login.bind(this)} />
```

Comment: I tired changing it to the above but the function is being called

Comment: Is it being called automatically? I didn't get you.

Comment: It;s not navigating nor am I getting any error, So I assumed its not calling the function

Comment: please try to `console.log()` or `alert` to check if it's working or not.

Comment: Do I need to change login into a arrow function?

Comment: Ok will try that

Comment: Function is being called

Comment: please try to  `console.log(this.props.navigation)` in `constructor`, is it `undefined`?